# Python self referential dictionary with class

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a list of parameters as a dictionary within a class.
Because of the nature of the data some of the parameters are derived from others, but used sufficiently often that I would prefer to keep their derivation within the parameters dictionary.
I've managed to put together a self-referential dictionary which works fine when I can name the dictionary directly, but because it's part of a class and may be implemented in lots of different files I'm having difficulty in getting it to be able to name itself.

```
class foo:
    class ParamDict(dict):
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
            return callable(val) and val() or val

    params = ParamDict({
        'a': 5,
        'b': lambda: 2**self['a']
        })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    X = foo()
    Y = foo()
    Y.params['a'] = 3

    print X.params['a'], X.params['b']
    print Y.params['a'], Y.params['b']
```

Because I don't know where the lambda function will be called from I don't know how to give it a reference to the dictionary, it doesn't seem to pick up the 'self' from the **getitem** definition, unfortunately.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you pass `self` to `val` in `__getitem__`? `return callable(val) and val(self) or val`? Obviously lambda would have to receive self: `'b': lambda self: 2**self['a']`.

Comment: Any reason not to use functions for what they are meant?

Comment: You cannot refer to `self` without an instance. When defining a class, there is no instance *yet*. If `self` in the `b` parameter is meant to refer to the `params` instance, then you need to *pass that into* the function.

Comment: @gatto, thank you - see my reply to Martijn below

Comment: @Secator care to elaborate? If I'm doing something very wrong then I'm open to new suggestions!

Comment: I just try understand what you're trying to achieve and what is the benefit of having custom `params` with dict-like way of accessing values instead of i.e `@propety` syntax or old-school getters/setters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self` doesn't just magically appear; Python functions are wrapped in methods when accessed via an instance (through [invoking the function as a descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors)), and `self` is then passed in to the function as a first argument.

For your lambdas, you'll need to pass `self` in *explicitly*:

```
class ParamDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        return callable(val) and val(self) or val

params = ParamDict({
    'a': 5,
    'b': lambda self: 2**self['a']
    })
```

Comment: Yes, thank you - that works to a point, I knew I'd been missing something there. When doing it this way though it does seem to modify the underlying class dictionary rather than an instance of the class dictionary (in the code above changing Y.params also changes X.params) although I think this might be me not quite getting my head around what's going on underneath.

Comment: @benjsec: That's because `params` is a *class attribute*. If you need per-instance copies of `params`, then create it in the `__init__` of the class.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, can you replace `callable(val) and val(self) or val` with the contemporary `val(self) if callable(val) else val`?

Comment: Ideally I should be able to get away with just `'b': 2**self['a']`, with an implicit persistent `lambda` assumption, and have it evaluated at calltime too. And I don't mean this by declaring every value as an executable string either. But if we can get there, we would've likely transcended Python.

Comment: @A-B-B absolutely! And that's a better idea all around; I was merely copying the OP there.

Comment: @A-B-B you can't get there with Python, because Python will try to evaluate that expression directly rather than store a callable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes, but perhaps at least the universal `self` argument can be automated w/o difficulty. In effect, I should then just have to type `'b': lambda: 2**self['a']`. Is this reasonably possible with an adjustment to `__getitem__`?

Comment: @A-B-B you can't, no, because Python won't know how to resolve the `self` name there. There is no closure from which to take it, etc. the only way is what I already gave in my answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, but `self` does not have to be resolved when the lambda is defined, only when the lambda is executed.

Comment: @A-B-B Python determines the scope of names when compiling which really means that *yes*, `self` needs to be defined when the lambda is created.

Comment: @A-B-B moreover, there is nothing in `__getitem__` to mark `self` there as a free variable to be closed over. Nested scopes cannot just be created dynamically at runtime like that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, then why is `foo = lambda: 2*bar` valid by itself w/o `bar` being defined first? Similarly, `b = lambda: 2**self['a']` is valid all by itself.

Comment: @A-B-B what you are asking for requires deep voodoo and recreation of both the `__getitem__` function object with an artificial nested scope, *and* recreating the lambda function objects with a forced `self` closure then rebuild again to attach it to the closed-over `self` in `__getitem__`. It could theoretically be done but is *way* too much pain all because you cannot be bothered to give the lambda a measly single argument.

Comment: @A-B-B because in that case `bar` and `self` are looked up as *globals* and you'll get a `NameError` when you call the lambda. A name is global unless found in a parent scope or bound to locally. This is, again, determined at compile time.

Comment: @A-B-B now you could first set `globals()['self'] = self` then call the lambda but then you lose all thread safety and are very likely to see strange bugs to do with mixing up instance references. Not recommended.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, in the code in the question, how about just replacing `self['a']` with `params['a']`? It seems to work and lambda doesn't then need an arg. What can go wrong? I guess the limitation then is that it'll work only if the lambdas are in the same scope as `params`.

Comment: @A-B-B: sure, that'll work because `params` is a name in a parent scope (either a closure or a global). But that also makes your lambda's sensitive to the global being rebound to a different name (not common, but not unheard of), and not reusable between instances.